# Is a manifold-with-boundary with given interior and non-empty boundary essentially unique?

Tags: differential-topology, manifolds

Let $M$ be a compact connected manifold-with-boundary such that $\circ M \neq \emptyset$, where $\circ M$ is the boundary of $M$. Let $N$ be a compact connected manifold-with-boundary such that $\circ N \neq \emptyset$ and $\bullet M \approx \bullet N$, where $\bullet M$ denotes the interior of $M$ and $\approx$ denotes homeomorphic. Does it necessarily hold that $N \approx M$?

(I have asked this question before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3169301/51161), but there were no replies.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, there are examples detected by Whitehead torsion. If $P$ is a compact connected $(n-1)$-manifold with empty boundary, then (assuming $n\ge 6$) for every element $\tau$ of the Whitehead group of $\pi_1(P)$ there is an $h$-cobordism $M$ on $P$ such that $\tau$ is the Whitehead torsion of the pair $(M,P)$. The interior of $M$ will be isomorphic to $P\times\mathbb R$, but if $\tau$ is nontrivial then $M$ will not be isomorphic to $P\times I$.

Comment: Thank you. I do not yet understand the answer; I will have to read about Whitehead torsion tomorrow. Would the same answer apply if $M$ and $N$ were orientable?

Comment: Yes, it has nothing to do with orientability.

Comment: How do I find a compact connected manifold $P$ with a non-trivial Whitehead group $Wh(\pi_1(P))$?

Comment: You can use a lens space. Many finite cyclic groups have nontrivial Whitehead groups.